# Save multiple RecordEditForm in lighting component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, community, lightning-recordeditform

I am trying to create a lighting component to save multiple records using a single click.

So, I am using lighting recordEditForm in aura:iterate. Here is code but I cannot save the data.

```
<aura:iteration items="1,2,3" var="iterate">
        <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="editForm"
                objectApiName="Contact">
                <!-- the messages component is for error messages -->
                <lightning:messages />
                <lightning:inputField fieldName="FirstName" />
                <lightning:inputField fieldName="LastName" />
                <lightning:inputField fieldName="AccountId" />
        </lightning:recordEditForm>
    </aura:iteration>
    <div class="slds-m-top_medium">
        <lightning:button variant="brand" type="submit" 
                          name="save" label="Save" onclick="{!c.handleSubmit}"  />
    </div>
```

and controller:

```
({
    handleSubmit : function(component, event, helper) {
       component.find("editForm").forEach(form => form.saveRecord(
        result => {

        })
      );


    }
})
```

I am getting an error as:

```
Uncaught Action failed: c:recordEditForm$controller$handleSubmit [form.saveRecord is not a function]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
<lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="editForm"
```

Here aura:id is `editForm`, so, you should use **component.find("editForm")** instead of *component.find("recordForm")*

```
handleSubmit : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.find("editForm").forEach(form => form.submit());
}
```

You should use `submit` method on form

Comment: Now I am getting this : 
Uncaught Action failed: c:recordEditForm$controller$handleSubmit [form.saveRecord is not a function]

Comment: saveRecord() is not a method of the RecordEditForm. Do you mean to call submit()? Is there a reason you are trying to do this without Apex? Looping through and submitting a RecordEditForm multiple times is terribly inefficient... and brings up other issues (e.g. what do you do if one record fails?) Calling an Apex method would be more efficient and provide better control.

Comment: added in answer - you should use submit